# How to call Snackbar to load when page is ready?

Tags: jquery, material-design

This is the code I have:

```
<script>
$('.body').ready(function() { 
   Snackbar.show({text: 'Example notification text.'}); 
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to get this little snackbar to show when the page has loaded, but so far I'm not getting anything.

Answer (score 2):

You should use document.ready instead of body.ready

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
   Snackbar.show({text: 'Example notification text.'}); 
});
</script>
```

Hope this solves your problem.